# Write variable from AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

So I'm doing an app what I'm trying to use a AlertDialog to write a variable on a PLC.  I want to make it so that every time you click the button the var increments by 1.  It almost works other than it only execute once.  So when I click the Speed Up button it increments, but if I click it again, it doesn't increment again.  If I then select the Speed Down button it will decrease the value by 1, (as it's suppose to) but once again, it won't execute again if I click the button again.  I'm very new to this type of programming.  Any help would be appreciated though!

```
public void ShowPopUpMenus(View v) {
final AlertDialog.Builder sayWindows = new AlertDialog.Builder(WritesActivity.this);

sayWindows.setPositiveButton("Speed Up", null);
sayWindows.setNegativeButton("Close", null);
sayWindows.setNeutralButton("speed Down", null);
//sayWindows.setAdapter(listWords, null);
//sayWindows.setView(saySomething);

sayWindows.setTitle("                  Machine Speed");  //Title!

final AlertDialog mAlertDialog = sayWindows.create();
mAlertDialog.setMessage("                                    " + sMachineSpeedTemp);  //Center Text, Probably not the correct way to do this. :)

mAlertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {

        //while (bDummy== false) {
        Button button_Speed_Up = mAlertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        button_Speed_Up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    MlpiConnection device = m_app.getDevice();
                    device.connect("192.168.0.5");

                    if (device.isConnected()) {
                        sMachineSpeedTemp = (device.logic().readVariableBySymbolAsString("Application.UserVarGlobal.sMachineSpeed_gb"));
                        iMachineSpeedTemp = Integer.parseInt(sMachineSpeedTemp);
                        iMachineSpeedTemp++;
                        device.logic().writeVariableBySymbolAsString("Application.UserVarGlobal.sMachineSpeed_gb", sMachineSpeedTemp);
                        sMachineSpeedTemp = iMachineSpeedTemp.toString();
                        mAlertDialog.setMessage("" + sMachineSpeedTemp);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mAlertDialog.setMessage("bad connection");
                    }
                }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                    Context c = v.getContext();
                    Toast.makeText(c, e + "Connection Error UP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        });

        Button button_Speed_Down = mAlertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
        button_Speed_Down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    MlpiConnection device = m_app.getDevice();
                    device.connect("192.168.0.5");

                    if (device.isConnected()) {
                        sMachineSpeedTemp = (device.logic().readVariableBySymbolAsString("Application.UserVarGlobal.sMachineSpeed_gb"));
                        iMachineSpeedTemp = Integer.parseInt(sMachineSpeedTemp);
                        iMachineSpeedTemp--;
                        device.logic().writeVariableBySymbolAsString("Application.UserVarGlobal.sMachineSpeed_gb", sMachineSpeedTemp);
                        sMachineSpeedTemp = iMachineSpeedTemp.toString();
                        mAlertDialog.setMessage(sMachineSpeedTemp);
                        mAlertDialog.setMessage("" + sMachineSpeedTemp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mAlertDialog.setMessage("bad connection");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Context c = v.getContext();
                    Toast.makeText(c, e + "Connection Error Down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        });

    }

});

mAlertDialog.show();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you are executing the code below every time you click on the button. This line `iMachineSpeedTemp = Integer.parseInt(sMachineSpeedTemp);` will override the value of `iMachineSpeedTemp` and increment it once so you will keep getting the same value.`

```
if (device.isConnected()) {
     sMachineSpeedTemp = device.logic().readVariableBySymbolAsString("Application.UserVarGlobal.sMachineSpeed_gb"));
     iMachineSpeedTemp = Integer.parseInt(sMachineSpeedTemp);
     iMachineSpeedTemp++;
     device.logic().writeVariableBySymbolAsString("Application.UserVarGlobal.sMachineSpeed_gb", sMachineSpeedTemp);
     sMachineSpeedTemp = iMachineSpeedTemp.toString();
     mAlertDialog.setMessage("" + sMachineSpeedTemp);
}
```

A possible solution is to a boolean flag

```
public class MyClass{

  private int iMachineSpeedTemp;
  private boolean isConnected = false;

}
```

Then you can check if `isConnected` is true

```
if (device.isConnected()) {
    if(isConnected){
       iMachineSpeedTemp++
    }else{
       sMachineSpeedTemp = device.logic().readVariableBySymbolAsString("Application.UserVarGlobal.sMachineSpeed_gb"));
       iMachineSpeedTemp = Integer.parseInt(sMachineSpeedTemp);
       iMachineSpeedTemp++;
       isConnected = true;
   }   
   device.logic().writeVariableBySymbolAsString("Application.UserVarGlobal.sMachineSpeed_gb", sMachineSpeedTemp);
   sMachineSpeedTemp = iMachineSpeedTemp.toString();
   mAlertDialog.setMessage("" + sMachineSpeedTemp);
 }
```

Comment: Ok.  One problem is that the value won't be at 0 though.  The value is being read off another device and it could be anything.  So I will have to read the value when I first start the activity and then increment from that value, which could be anything.  At least that's my current plan of attack,  could be backwards, idk...

Answer (score 0):

```
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            MlpiConnection device = m_app.getDevice();
                            device.connect("192.168.0.5");
                            if (device.isConnected()) {
                                    sMachineSpeedTemp = device.logic().readVariableBySymbolAsString("Application.UserVarGlobal.sMachineSpeed_gb");
                                    iMachineSpeedTemp = Integer.parseInt(sMachineSpeedTemp);
                                    iMachineSpeedTemp++;
                                    sMachineSpeedTemp = Integer.toString(iMachineSpeedTemp);
                                    device.logic().writeVariableBySymbolAsString("Application.UserVarGlobal.sMachineSpeed_gb", sMachineSpeedTemp);
                                    mAlertDialog.setMessage("                                   " + sMachineSpeedTemp);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: This fixed it.  The only difference that I can see if the - 

sMachineSpeedTemp = Integer.toString(iMachineSpeedTemp);

vs

sMachineSpeedTemp = iMachineSpeedTemp.toString();

Either way, it works.  For now...  Thanks for the help Nolly J